# Creating a Python library supporting Django and Pyramid

Tags: python, django, shared-libraries, pyramid

I currently have three libraries that log errors. One for Django, one for Pyramid, and one for plain Python. They all currently have separate implementations to do the same thing, log errors and messages in a specific way.

I would like to consolidate them all into one library so that new features do not have to be duplicated across three separate libraries. Users would just need to install the one library and then be able to choose whether they want Django or Pyramid support.

One solution would be to stick the Django and Pyramid code into the plain Python library and have both web frameworks share the same logging code. Another solution would be to keep the web frameworks in separate libraries but with the logging implementations stripped out, and put into the plain Python library making it a dependency.

What would be the recommended way about doing this? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Django at least uses the standard built-in Python logging library. Why can't you use that?

Comment: So does Pyramid; presumably the OP has something built on top of that?

Comment: Yes, my libraries take the logs and send them to a web app, among other things.

Comment: I would build a base library with all the common code and a well defined API, and then build lightweight wrappers around it to tackle specific issues in each framework. Anyway, it's kinda hard to tell what is the best way without knowing what your library *actually does*.

Comment: It's quite common to have package `x`, with framework-specific packages which depend on it, `django-x` and `pyramid_x`.

Answer (score 0):

Factor out all of the code that is common (and can be made common) across all of your libraries. Then, if required, create submodules specific to each framework that tie into their various features and idioms.

Check out [Raven](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). They do exactly this (and they're also a log-sending library!)